# Setting NSF file Full Text Index Update Frequency (Server Only)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Previously in application property Update frequency (Server only) - "Immediate"

I have changed it into "Daily", (In Application property -> Full Text Tab -> Update frequency (Server only) -> Daily) but is not getting affected. Full text happening frequently ((i.e.)2mins interval).

Please suggest what may be the reason?

Comment: 2 minutes this is NOT standard ! maybe have you a program that run every 2 min (look in Administrator, configuration, Server, programs)

Answer (score 0):

Frequency "Immediate" updates the index using the update task
Frequency "Daily" updates the index using the updall task

Try to restart the update task. if this is not working try to delete the fulltext index and recreate it using the "Daily" setting